# Adazzle Grid OnEdit change cell Css

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-data-grid

For react, is it possible to change the cell color for a component? I know it is way super easy can be done in Jquery by looking at the id/class of the element and do an addClass, but how to do it on react? I'm still figuring it out the changes,  what i can think of is that i set the value on a state, but how i get the affected cell and implement the state? Any idea? Or is there any better grid that I can achieve like what can be done in Jquery?

```
 constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            cellUpdateCss: ""
        };
    }

handleGridRowsUpdated = ({ cellKey, fromRow, toRow, updated, action, originRow }) => {
        let rows = this.state.rows.slice();

        for (let i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++) {
            let rowToUpdate = rows[i];
            let updatedRow = update(rowToUpdate, { $merge: updated });
            rows[i] = updatedRow;
            this.postToServer(updatedRow.data, JSON.stringify(updated));
        }

        this.setState({ rows });
    };

postToServer = (aX, vC) => {
        var self = this;
        axios.post(this.props.postApi, {
            axNo: aX,
            updated: vC
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            self.setState({ cellUpdateCss: "green" });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            self.setState({ cellUpdateCss: "red" });
        });
    }

render() {
     return (
      <ReactDataGrid
            onGridRowsUpdated={this.handleGridRowsUpdated} 
           />
      )
}
```

third party grid that I use
https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by applying the style to the row class name, first of all, in `handleGridRowsUpdated` function you need to set `fromRow, toRow` to the constructor state then we need to call the `changeStyle` function that I did with the callback of `setState`.

```
  handleGridRowsUpdated = ({ cellKey, fromRow, toRow, updated, action, originRow }) => {
        let rows = this.state.rows.slice();

        for (let i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++) {
            let rowToUpdate = rows[i];
            let updatedRow = update(rowToUpdate, { $merge: updated });
            rows[i] = updatedRow;
            this.postToServer(updatedRow.data, JSON.stringify(updated));
        }

        this.setState({ rows, fromRow: fromRow, toRow: toRow },()=>{
             this.changeStyle(); 
         });
    };
```

`changeStyle` function, it will change the color of the edited row.

```
changeStyle = () => {
    var all = document.getElementsByClassName('react-grid-Row');
    for (var i = this.state.fromRow; i <= this.state.toRow; i++) {
      all[i].style.color = this.state.cellUpdateCss;
    }
  }
```

I did a full example on **CodeSandbox**

[image: Edit o7oy6j304z]